# (compile opencv2.4)Makefile:165: recipe for target 'all' failed

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, opencv3.0

When I compile opencv2.4, an error has occurred:

```
[ 79%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/test/test_positioning.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/test/test_video_io.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/test/test_video_pos.cpp.o
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_highgui
[ 80%] Built target opencv_test_highgui
Makefile:165: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@qrh-pc:/home/qrh/视频/software/opencv/opencv-2.4.13.6/build#
```

Could you help me understanding the cause of this error?

Comment: You'll really need to look at what is happening in more detail. It does appear from the output that at least `../../bin/opencv_test_highgui` has been built successfully, but there might be some more detail around line 165 of the `Makefile` about what it is trying to do, and there may be a build log somewhere with more detail - perhaps `ls -laR` in the current directory to find it.

Comment: I found that some libraries  such as cuda、ffmpeg， were not installed ，but i selected them during cmake configuration.Then i cancelled them and reconfigured,finally make it success.